# Is it possible to read post from facebook group via Open Graph?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to read via OpenGraph or Facebook SDK posts from group when I'm a member of this group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can access to it if you have a token and the group id, using this url : `https://graph.facebook.com/{OBJECT_ID}/feed?access_token`

Note that you can access only to public posts.